# how to use "if" statements inside pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, conditional-statements, statements

I'm trying to use `if` inside a pipeline.

I know that there is `where` (alias `?`) filter, but what if I want activate a filter only if a certain condition is satisfied?

I mean, for example:

```
get-something | ? {$_.someone -eq 'somespecific'} | format-table
```

How to use `if` inside the pipeline to switch the filter on/off? Is it possible? Does it make sense?

Thanks

**EDITED to clarify**

Without pipeline it would look like this:

```
if($filter) {
 get-something | ? {$_.someone -eq 'somespecific'}
}
else {
 get-something
}
```

---

**EDIT after ANSWER's riknik**

Silly example showing what I was looking for. You have a denormalized table of data stored on a variable `$data` and you want to perform a kind of "drill-down" data filtering:

```
function datafilter {
param([switch]$ancestor,
    [switch]$parent,
    [switch]$child,
    [string]$myancestor,
    [string]$myparent,
    [string]$mychild,
    [array]$data=[])

$data |
? { (!$ancestor) -or ($_.ancestor -match $myancestor) } |
? { (!$parent) -or ($_.parent -match $myparent) } |
? { (!$child) -or ($_.child -match $mychild) } |

}
```

For example, if I want to filter by a specific parent only:

`datafilter -parent -myparent 'myparent' -data $mydata`

That's very elegant, performant and simple way to exploit `?`. Try to do the same using `if` and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: I think you mean to write:

get-something | ? { $_.someone -eq 'somespecific' } | format-table    

You have ( and ) instead of { and }.

Comment: @x0n: you are true, I've just corrected the miscode. Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20123883/223837 for another answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using where-object, the condition doesn't have to strictly be related to the objects that are passing through the pipeline. So consider a case where sometimes we wanted to filter for odd objects, but only if some other condition was met:

```
$filter = $true
1..10 | ? { (-not $filter) -or ($_ % 2) }

$filter = $false
1..10 | ? { (-not $filter) -or ($_ % 2) }
```

Is this kind of what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, reading your answer more carefully and trying some silly test, I've found it useful. Thanks. I'm going to edit my original question inserting some clarification on how such a logic can be used.

Comment: Cool, glad it could help. It's nice and compact, if a bit unclear on what it's doing. :) I now understand a bit more about what you're trying to do, now that I see that you want to chain multiple potential filters in the pipeline. Neat idea. :)

Comment: Nice.  I used this approach when filtering values when a parameter was supplied, while ignoring the filter if the parameter wasn't supplied: `Where-Object { -not $Path -or $_.Path -like $Path }`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating your own filter. (A silly) example:

```
filter MyFilter {
   if ( ($_ % 2) -eq 0) { Write-Host $_ }
   else { Write-Host ($_ * $_) }
}

PS> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 | MyFilter
1
2
9
4
25
6
49
8
81
```

Comment: Thanks, however in your example there is no way to command filtering.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can have parameters to filters just like to a function. That way you get better control over how the filter works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my answer can help you but I try :)

```
1..10 | % {if ($_ % 2 -eq 0) {$_}}
```

as you can see I use a loop and for each number between 1 and 10 I check if is even and I display it only in this case.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like a filter `1..10 | ? {($_ % 2) -eq 0}`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question then. Sorry.

Comment: What does % in '% {...}' mean please? Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance et al, it's shorthand for `Foreach-Object`, [more here](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html).