# Possible to have conditional pipes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Say I only want to pipe my output to another function depending on the value of a variable, is there some way to do this in powershell?

Example :

```
 if ($variable -eq "value"){$output | AnotherFunction}
  else {$output}
```

@mjolinor's example is how I am doing it now, just curious if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: -1 - give some explanation of what you want to do. @mjolinor 's anwser is appropriate, but I would have thought it to be trivial.

Comment: Might be trivial.  I haven't used PowerShell before so I'm trying to figure out if there is a more elegant way to do it.  Sorry if I offended you.

Comment: I don't know if you'd consider it "more elegant" or not, but you can implement that logic as a filter.  I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20123883/223837 for another answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an If clause:

```
 if ($variable -eq "value"){$output | AnotherFunction}
  else {$output}
```

Example implemented as a fiter:

```
 filter myfilter{
   if ($variable -eq "value"){$_ | AnotherFunction}
   else {$_}
 }
```

Then:

```
 $variable = <some value>
 get-something | myfilter
```

Answer (score 3):

You may get the results you are looking for by piping to the [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx).

Example:

`My-Command | Where-Object {$variable -eq "value"} | AnotherFunction`

Comment: I don't see how that would allow conditional piping.  Do you have an example?

Comment: Do you want to output to different functions depending on the output, or do you want to output to 1 function, but only if the output is what you want it to be?

Comment: Pretty much the way that @mjolinor has it setup.  I was wondering if there was a better way, but it sounds like there might not be.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. AnotherFunction will get passed only what passes the condition of Where-Object.

Comment: But when $variable -eq "value" is $false, nothing is returned. That's why this approach doesn't work.

Comment: @stej that is correct, but many functions/cmdlets will gracefully exit when passed nothing. Try running `Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.handles -lt 100} | Format-List`, then change the 100 to 0 and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

If the other function is yours, you can send $variable as a parameter and let your function pass the object through unmodified when param is true. Essentially, you use AnotherFunction() as Mjolinor's filter.

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809736/how-to-use-if-statements-inside-pipeline) I've asked how to use `if` statements inside pipeline. It demonstrates how to pipe data to other functions based on conditions.